# Can not find the reason why my "enter end number(0-16):" prompt keeps looping. My start prompt will stop looping but my end won't any suggestions?

Tags: loops, assembly, lc3

```
.ORIG x3000



;clear registers 

AND R0, R0, #0                                          ; clear RO
AND R1, R1, #0                                          ; clear R1
AND R2, R2, #0                                          ; clear R2
AND R3, R3, #0                                          ; clear R3
AND R4, R4, #0                                          ; clear R4
AND R5, R5, #0                                          ; clear R5
AND R6, R6, #0                                          ; clear R6







;print "Enter Start Number(0-16):" and get the start number on the same line

RESTARTS            LEA R0, START
                    PUTS
                    GETC
                    OUT
                
; move starting number value into a different register

ADD R3, R0, #0                                          ; R0 data moved to R3               

START .STRINGZ "\n\nEnter Start Number(0-16):"

                                                                                                        ;check bounds on start number
        LD R5, NASCII                                   ; R5 loaded with #-57
        ADD R6, R3, R5                                  ; R6 = R3 + #-57
        BRn RESTARTS                                    ; when value is negative branch to restart
        
        LD R5, ADSCII
        ADD R1, R3, R5
        BRp RESTARTS













;print "Enter End number(0-16):"
 
 
RESTARTE        LEA R0, END
                PUTS 
                GETC 
                OUT
                                                                                                        ; Check bounds
        
        
        
        
        LD R5, NASCII
        ADD R6, R4, R5
        BRn RESTARTE
        
        LD R5, ADSCII
        ADD R1, R4, R5
        BRp RESTARTE



HALT


END .STRINGZ "\n\nEnter End number(0-16):"

; move the end number into a different register

ADD R4, R0, #0                                          ; R0 data moved to R4


; R0 data now free








; check if number is within bounds

        



 ; reset R6 and R1 
        
        AND R1, R1, #0
        AND R6, R6, #0
        
; can use R6 and R1 cleared above

    


;convert register R3(start number) into a keyboard character (strip ascii)
                
                
    LD R1, NASCII
        ADD R3, R3, R1      ; R3 = -48 + x
    
        ADD R4, R4, R1      ; R4 = -48 + y
        
NASCII .FILL #-48
ADSCII .FILL #-57
    
    
; make the program find odd values between entered values


                










; add the odd numbers between the values entered 



;print "the sum of every odd number between the two numbers is:"



.END
```

Comment: Your second loop seems to rely on some value being in `R4` that you haven't set. Also, why are you placing strings in the middle of an instruction sequence? How is the CPU going to know that it shouldn't interpret the string data as a bunch of (garbage) instructions and try to execute them?

Comment: As Michael says, don't mix code & data.  Move all the data to after all the code.